# Drawing Shapes problem when popup Menu bar

Tags: java, swing

I am working on a project "Draw Simple Shapes". I have a menu to choose option to draw shapes like rectangle, oval, and round rectangle.

My problem here is: when menu popup, my shape which under the menu is lost a part. And I see problem here is the menu bar and its menu items incumbent my shape in JPanel.

[shape when popup menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MnC1i.png)

[shape after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bszun.png)

How can I fix the problem?

Here is my code to draw shapes (it is not also set color for background and shape)

```
public class DrawingShape extends javax.swing.JFrame {

  Graphics g = null;
  Point p1 = null, p2 = null;
  String drawOption = "rectangle";
   
  public DrawingShape() {
    initComponents();      
    this.setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    
 }
 


public void drawShape() {
    g = jPanel1.getGraphics();
    int x = p1.x < p2.x ? p1.x : p2.x;
    int y = p1.y < p2.y ? p1.y : p2.y;
  
    int width = (p1.x - p2.x) * size;
    if (width < 0) {
        width = -width;
    }
    int height = (p1.y - p2.y) * size;
    if (height < 0) {
        height = -height;
    }

    switch (drawOption) {
        case "rectangle": {
            g.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
            break;
        }
        case "oval": {
            g.fillOval(x, y, width, height);
            break;
        }
        case "round rect": {
            g.fillRoundRect(x, y, width, height, 10 * size, 10 * size);
            break;
        }
        default: {
            break;
        }

    }
}

private void miRectangleActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
            drawOption = "rectangle";
        }                                           
    
        private void miOvalActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
            drawOption = "oval";
        }                                      
    
        private void miRoundRectActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
            drawOption = "round rect";
        }  


        private void jPanel1MousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
            p1 = evt.getPoint();
        }                                    

        private void jPanel1MouseReleased(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
            p2 = evt.getPoint();
            drawShape();
        }                    
         

      }
```

Comment: Where is drawShape called?

Comment: Yeah, this isn't how Swing works.  Have you read the tutorials?

Comment: @AmirAfghani  Oh, may be I missed something so important about Swing, can you give the best tutorial you think for me, please?

Comment: I think Amir may be referring to your call of `Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH` instead of JFrame. Generally, mixing AWT and Swing isn't advised. Your code also needs some refactoring. For example, you initialize `g = jPanel1.getGraphics()` but we don't know what jPanel1 is. You may also consider overriding the `paintComponent()` method. In addition, have you tried the `repaint()` method?

Comment: You should have a paintComponent method in your panels, and update their graphics in there.  This, and what Pranav said.

Comment: See [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) lesson which is part of Oracle's java tutorials.

Comment: `jPanel1.getGraphics();` is not how you do custom painting, see the link by Abra for more details